# Background image on jade tamplete

Tags: css, node.js, pug

I'm using node js (without express) and I have problem with background image url
.jade file

```
extends ../node_modules/pug-bootstrap/_bootstrap
block body
  style
    include style.css
```

style.css file:

```
body{
    background: #222 url('skyscrapers.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
```

it seems like the background color works but the img not loaded.
I check it in simple HTML file and everything work fine.
The location of the img are correct to.

Comment: What happens if you split up `background` into `background-color`, `-image`, `-position`, and `-repeat`?

Comment: try it..still not working

Answer (score 0):

The image will be loaded relative to the resulting HTML file.  Make sure that the `skyscrapers.jpg` file is in the same folder as the HTML output you are generating.

Comment: It is in the same file that .pug file and  HTML file are

Comment: How are you loading the resulting HTML?  Are you compiling the pug to a file and saving that in the same folder?

Comment: I use `writeHead()` function like this                                                    `var html = pug.renderFile('views/index.pug');
   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
   res.write(html);
   res.end();`

Comment: That shouldn't work at all.  You don't have a file system in your browser, so can't do `pug.renderFile`.  I suggest using the pug-cli to render the file in advance using node.js then just serve the resulting HTML directly.